# How to always make page content appear beneath navigation bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, positioning

I want to keep the content of my page to always appear beneath the navigation bar, similar to how this page works:

http://www.google.com/intl/en/enterprise/apps/business/products.html#calendar

You can scroll down or up in the content, but the navigation bar never goes away.

For this purpose, I've used `position:fixed` to fix the navigation bar to the top of the page. This works, but I'm still able to scroll the content up and down, causing it to run 'through' and over the navigation bar, when I want the content to always be pushed below the navigation bar.

Any ideas on how to do this? Here's my css code for the `<ul id='navigation'>` containing the navigation:

```
#navigation
{
    text-align: center; 
    position: fixed; 
    float: left;    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#navigation li
{
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 150px;
    height: 110px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And here's the css for the `<div id="container">` which appears below `#navigation` and holds all of the page content body:

```
#container
{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 180px;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: http://dropthebit.com/demos/stickyfloat/stickyfloat.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's going through is because you didn't set a background color to your navigation bar. Try that.

Edit: Looked at your source code. Replace navigation CSS in style.css file with this:

```
#navigation
{
    text-align: center; 
    position: fixed; 
    float: left;    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index:999;
}
```

The problem was the z-index. Putting it at 999 puts the navigation bar on top of all other elements.

Comment: Is there no other way? Even when I set the background, I can see the content running through

Comment: See my updated comment. I took your source code and got it working.

Comment: Thanks mate, so it was the z-index that needed to be really high?

Comment: You can try changing it around. I think z-index of 10 would work too. I just have a habit (don't know if it's a bad one) of putting it super high. In the end, you had to have both background-color set and z-index set in order for it to work properly. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the property z-index:xxx, did you try that?

Comment: for instance, add z-index:1 to the container, and z-index:10 to the nav bar, this should do the trick. this article http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/ is very clearly explained :)

Comment: I find the content still scrolls over the navigation bar even with z-index set like that  https://jsfiddle.net/d7wd2pwg/43/

Answer (score 1):

Years ago created my site with that same functionality.  I opted for Server Side Includes and it works great.  I created a 'header' the navigation links and a 'footer' that gets included on each page.

Comment: Server side includes are known to be bad, security-wise though. I would not recommend that solution.

Comment: I'm already using PHP includes for showing the header and footer. I don't see how that would solve this problem though.

Comment: Hmmm, didn't know that.  Thanks for the heads up.  I'll have to research that.

Comment: Seems that the security issues are a concern for the server admin, not the website developer.  And for basic navigation is still a great example.

Comment: Click Upvote, I am using an image file as a background to my ssi with the nav links over that.  I don't have any issues with the scroll-able content bleeding into the ssi.  Check out [link](http://www.57heaven.net).  It's just a small hobby site running PHP/CSS.  The main page doesn't scroll but most of the others do.

Comment: Isn't that because of the CSS?

Comment: Isn't what because of the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add `data-role="header"` ?

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't pay attention that it was for regular jquery, my answer was for jquery mobile.
http://jsfiddle.net/3zzs3/